flutter build apk file error while using messbio flutter sdk
I'm working on a Flutter project that uses the Mesibo SDK for chat functionality. When trying to build the APK, I encounter the following error:
ERROR: Missing classes detected while running R8. Please add the missing classes or apply additional keep rules that are generated in .
ERROR: R8: Missing class android.window.BackEvent (referenced from: void io.flutter.view.FlutterView.startBackGesture(android.window.BackEvent) and 1 other context)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_inappwebview:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable
   > Compilation failed to complete

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

I reviewed the missing_rules.txt file generated in
The missing class is android.window.BackEvent.
How can I resolve the missing android.window.BackEvent class?
Are there specific keep rules that I need to add to prevent R8 from stripping necessary classes?
Is there a compatibility issue between the Flutter SDK, Android SDK versions, and Mesibo SDK that I need to address?

Can you share your proguard rules?

we do not have proguard rules file in our projects

First, go inside the Android folder, then within the app directory, locate the build.gradle file.
Inside the android {} block, set the following:
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

Try this configuration. If it doesn't work, set the following two properties to false:
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true

